# Menu that filters elements by range between two input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a filtering dropdown menu, basically like the one found on this [site](http://damienhirst.com/artworks/catalogue)

What I got to work are filters that select items from a category

What I want to add are the two fields with years, which let you select a range of years (e.g from 1988 up to 2014) which will filter for all items that match the years within that range. It needs to be compatible with other filters for type, category etc. like described above. Can anyone tell me how this is done?

```js
$(".filterOptions").click(function() {

var ChosenType = $('#typeOption').find(':selected').attr('value');
var ChosenSize = $('#sizeOption').find(':selected').attr('value');


$('.thumbnail').css('display', 'none');
var selector = '.thumbnail';


if (ChosenType != "all") {
  selector += '[data-type-option="' + ChosenType + '"]';
}

if (ChosenSize != "all") {
  selector += '[data-size-option="' + ChosenSize + '"]';
}

$(selector).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="typeOption" class="filterOptions">
    <option  value="all">All</option>
    <option  value="type1">type1</option>
    <option  value="type2">type2</option>
    <option  value="type3">type3</option>
</select>

<select id="sizeOption" class="filterOptions">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="small">small</option>
    <option value="medium">medium</option>
    <option value="large">large</option>
</select>

<select id="startyear" class="filterOptions">
   <option value="all">from</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<select id="endyear" class="filterOptions">
   <option value="all">to</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type2" data-size-option="small" data-year-option="2015">content1</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type1" data-size-option="large" data-year-option="2016">content2</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type2" data-size-option="large" data-year-option="2017">content3</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type3" data-size-option="small" data-year-option="2018">content4</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type1" data-size-option="medium" data-year-option="2017">content5</div>
<div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type3" data-size-option="medium" data-year-option="2018">content6</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with relevant code to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your selected elements and check that the year is valid

```
if (ChosenType != "all") {
  selector += '[data-type-option="' + ChosenType + '"]';
}

if (ChosenCategory != "all") {
  selector += '[data-year-option="' + ChosenYear + '"]';
}
let startYr = ...; // make sure this is a number (not a string)
let endYr = ...; // make sure this is a number (not a string)
let elems = $(selector);
elems.each(function() {
   let yr = this.data-year-open; //select the year from your element. Make sure this is also a number
   if (yr >= startYr && yr <= endYr) $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: tried adding your code to my snippet above with:
let startYr = $('#startyear').find(':selected').attr('value');
let endYr = $('#endyear').find(':selected').attr('value'); 

I don`t know what to put at yr = ...;

Comment: @user1163818 I have updated my answer. Please try now

Answer (score 1):

You could use on `change` event to listener for select elements and then inside `filter` method to filter by type and category values and `hide` div elements accordingly.

```js
const divs = $('.thumbnail')

$("select").on('change', function() {
  var type = $('#typeOption').val()
  var cat = $('#categoryOption').val()
  divs.show()

  if (type != 'all') {
    divs.filter(function() {
      return type !== $(this).data('type-option')
    }).hide()
  }

  if (cat != 'all') {
    divs.filter(function() {
      return cat !== $(this).data('category-option')
    }).hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="typeOption">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="type1">1</option>
  <option value="type2">2</option>
  <option value="type3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="categoryOption">
  <option value="all">all</option>
  <option value="category1">1</option>
  <option value="category2">2</option>
  <option value="category3">3</option>
</select>

  <div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type2" data-category-option="category3">content 1</div>
  <div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type1" data-category-option="category3">content 2</div>
  <div class="thumbnail" data-type-option="type1" data-category-option="category2">content 3</div>
```